# Realm how to save item if not exist else it should update

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a data coming from webservice. I have same models made in my project. To demonstrate the model let me show a little idea of my model

**Model1:**

```
class Standard {
var Id = 0
var standardName = ""
var students : [StudentModel] = nil
}
```

**Model2:**

```
class StudentModel {
    var Id = 0
    var stdName = ""
    var Teacher: [TeacherModel] = nil
    }
```

**Model3:**

```
class TeacherModel {
    var Id = 0
    var Name = ""
   }
```

Now what I am facing is as follow :

> I have TeacherModel in DB already, but I dont have student model and standard model instance int he Realm, so it is supposed to save coming student and standard data in Realm. and skip or update TeacherModel in Realm. But right now it is crashing on TeachModel data as one Teacher with same things are already saved in Realm.SO i am looking forward to some sort of method in which it update or just skip saving Item if already exist in the Realm.

**Note:** These models are just to demonstrate my case, where as I know there are many typos and other thing. Also I did not showed any implementation of Realm over my Models. Its just to show you the things to make you understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to have `class func primaryKey() -> String?` overriden.

```
override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "Id"
}
```

And then use `realm.write(...)` or `realm.create(...)` functions with `update` parameter set to `true`.

Comment: Man I have set this. I mean Id is my primary key. I told you that these models are just dummy just to show you sequence

Comment: I just want if in writing, the Realm Found any object in the saving then it must update it

Comment: Well then you should provide the code how you save your models to Realm.

Comment: And yes Realm is able to update objects, you just have to tell him to do that by the `update: true` of `write`/`create` functions